# Ocaml loop for string printf

Tags: ocaml

```
let string s = "";;

let string s =
    for i = 0 to 5 do
    Printf.sprintf "%s" s
    done;;
```

[image]

I want to printf with string type in loop (ex-string "hi" -> "hihihihihi")
When I use for, It makes string to unit and It doesnt' work.
How to loop print with string type?

[image: Example image]

Comment: sprintf creates a new string. You want printf.

Comment: Printf.printf "%s" s; --> Still [  val string : string -> unit = <fun> ]/  Can I print [string -> string = <fun>] ?

Comment: I just noticed this... let string s = ""... Should be let s = "";

Comment: Please [don't post images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) (Note: I haven't actually downvoted, the site just provides a very good explanation)

Comment: OK. I removed Images.

Comment: Removing them doesn't improve the question. On the contrary, so I've reverted it. But converting them to plain text would.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. I will post like that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
let string_n_times s n =
  let str = ref "" in
  for i = 1 to n do
    str := !str ^ s
  done; !str

let () = print_endline (string_n_times "hi" 5)
```

Comment: You should not use repeated concatenation with `^`, it is unnecessarily quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to do it with a buffer or format, with the right complexity.

First, the more imperative version is probably with a buffer

```
let string_repeat_n_time s n =
   let b = Buffer.create (String.length s * n) in
   for i = 1 to n do
     Buffer.add_string b s
   done;
   Buffer.contents b
```

Buffer are made to handle efficiently repeated addition, so they are the right data structure.

A more functional version would be to use recursion with `Format.fprintf` (`Format` is essentially an improved version of `Printf`)

```
let string_n_times s n =
  let rec repeat ppf n = 
    if n = 0 then Format.fprintf ppf "%!"
    else
      Format.fprintf ppf "%s%a" s repeat (n-1) in
  Format.asprintf "%a" repeat n ;;
```

This code is using a `Buffer` under the hood thus the complexity is the same as before. If we make the buffer explicit, we can have an imperative code that is using the format printer

```
let string_n_times s n =
   let b = Buffer.create (String.length s * n) in
   let ppf = Format.formatter_of_buffer b in  
   for i = 1 to n do
      Format.fprintf ppf "%s" s
   done;
   Format.fprintf ppf "%!" (* flush *);
   Buffer.contents b
```

which can be useful if we are adding something more complex than a string to the buffer.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
let string_n_times s n =
  for i = 0 to n do
    Printf.printf "%s" s
  done

let () = string_n_times "Hi" 5
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is similar.///
But, Work on string. not unit ////
example ///

# string;;
-/// : string -> string = <fun>
# string "test";;
-/// : string = "testtest"
# string "apple";;
-/// : string = "appleapple"

Comment: If you want to use a loop to build up a string then you need a ref to hold that string